# Mastery Page "Temporary Changes"

Tags: league-of-legends

I thought of a situation that I'm not clear of for the mastery pages in League of Legends.

I have multiple mastery pages, for different types of champs (one for tanks, one for mages, one for support, etc. etc.).

But what I've noticed is depending on which champion I use of a certain type (one mage vs. another, etc) I may use different summoner spells, which means I occasionally might want to swap 1 mastery point in favor of a mastery supporting my summoner skill(s).  It doesn't seem worth having a whole separate page based on each setup of summoner skills, especially since I then have to remember which one is "Mastery Page 4", for instance.

You can edit your mastery pages once you're at the champion select screen, however.  But in most cases I don't want to make permanent changes and save them, because I prefer the original page.  Is there a way to change your mastery page for the CURRENT MATCH, such that it resets to the original on subsequent matches?

Comment: The fact that this is currently not possible has been brought up on the forums and [noted by Riot](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=777571), but it's not possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently the Answer is NO.

Once you click on "Save and Use" the masteries are saved to mastery page number X (Where X = 1-10).

I completely understand what you mean with using different summoner spells on the same champion role, so what I created was, different mastery pages for the same role each with a different combination of summoner spells, so for instance my mastery pages looks like:

[image]

The one last mastery page is left as a Configurable one during champion selection, so if someone else on my team has clairvoyance and I am playing a support champ, I can get instead of C.V flash or heal.

10 Mastery pages should be enough to customize your preferences.

**EDIT:**

> especially since I then have to remember which one is "Mastery Page 4"

You can change the mastery page name by simply clicking the default name and when done hitting ENTER.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know about the fact you could change names. I just resigned myself to memorize my pages (which is easy when you only have 3). Awesome to learn.

Comment: I'm always glad to find my answers useful :)

Comment: Renaming the mastery pages definitely would help.  I'd still like a temporary change but I guess this will do.  Thanks.

Comment: @Grace: You can do the same for Rune pages, by the way.